# Python Regex Nuance with Non-Capturing Group Containing $

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract these two dates from this string:

````
re.findall(r"(?:^|[^0-9])(1[012]|0?[1-9])[/-](1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]|0?[1-9])[/-](\d{2})(?:$| )", 'For the period from 7/1/22 through 8/31/22', flags=18)
[('7', '1', '22'), ('8', '31', '22')]```
````

Why don't I get that result when I use this regex (with slightly modified *ending*?

```
re.findall(r"(?:^|[^0-9])(1[012]|0?[1-9])[/-](1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]|0?[1-9])[/-](\d{2})(?:$|[^0-9]+)", 'For the period from 7/1/22 through 8/31/22', flags=18)
[('7', '1', '22')]
```

I know I'm missing something silly here; thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is `flags=18`?

Comment: In general, debuggers are your most powerful tools to troubleshoot non-working code. A web search will turn up various regex debuggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second regex doesn't match only the parts `7/1/22` and `8/31/22`. It matches `7/1/22 through` and  `8/31/22`.
They do overlap (the one space character) and `re.findall` returns only non-overlapping matches.

To fix that, I would propose to use lookahead and lookbehind.
You can change the beginning of the regex from `(?:^|[^0-9])` to `(?:^|(?<=[^0-9]))` and the end from `(?:$|[^0-9]+)` to `(?=$|[^0-9]+)`.
This way the matches won't contain additional characters and they won't overlap anymore.

More about lookahead and lookbehind: [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/3052438)

Answer (score 0):

Regex are difficult to read, debug and maintain. Whenever possible, I'd rather trade **performance** for **readability**.

In this case that would mean using a *much simpler regex*, and writing an additional function to unload the burden of checking whether the date is valid or not.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,4})')

def is_valid_date(m: re.Match):
    month = int(m.group(1))
    day = int(m.group(2))
    year = int(m.group(3))
    b1 = day > 0 and day <= 31
    b2 = month > 0 and month <= 12
    b3 = year > 0
    return b1 and b2 and b3
```

It gives you:

```
s = "For the period from 7/1/22 through 8/31/22, and 13/2/24 is not a valid date"

dates = [m for m in pattern.finditer(s) if is_valid_date(m)]

>>> [<re.Match object; span=(20, 26), match='7/1/22'>, <re.Match object; span=(35, 42), match='8/31/22'>]
```

If you want to output a list of tuples:

```
dates_tp = [(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)) for m in dates]
>>> [('7', '1', '22'), ('8', '31', '22')]
```

## edit

Actually it looks like this method is also slightly more performant:

```
pat_1 = r"(?:^|[^0-9])(1[012]|0?[1-9])[/-](1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]|0?[1-9])[/-](\d{2})(?:$| )"
def method_1(s):
    res = re.findall(pat_1, s, flags=18)
    return res

pat_2 = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,4})')
def is_valid_date(m: re.Match):
    month = int(m.group(1))
    day = int(m.group(2))
    year = int(m.group(3))
    b1 = day > 0 and day <= 31
    b2 = month > 0 and month <= 12
    b3 = year > 0
    return b1 and b2 and b3
def method_2(s):
    dates_tp = [(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)) for m in pat_2.finditer(s) if is_valid_date(m)]
    return dates_tp
```

```
import timeit

timeit.timeit("method_1(s)", globals=globals(), number=1000000)
>>> 5.62

timeit.timeit("method_2(s)", globals=globals(), number=1000000)
>>> 4.85
```